# Use getgrnam() to only query local groups

Tags: linux, perl, ldap

I am attempting to integrate a standalone product into an LDAP environment.

I have a RHEL 6.7 system that is configured for ldap authentication (via sss) that I need to programmatically add local users and groups to.

The input xml file has a list of users and groups with their group membership, login shell, user id and group id that should be used.

Now comes the problem, I have a Perl script that uses the XML file to configure the users and groups, it uses the getgrnam and getpwnam to query for users and groups then makes a system call to groupmod/groupadd and usermod/useradd if the user exists or not. I found that if LDAP has a group the same name as the group I am trying to create my script will see the group as existing and jump to the groupmod instead of groupadd. Then group binaries will only perform operations on local groups, and fail because the group doesn't exist locally. NSS is setup to check files then sss, which make sense why getgrnam returns the ldap group.

Is there a way to have getgrnam and getpwnam only query the local system without having to reconfigure nsswitch.conf and possibly stop/start SSSD when I run the script?

Is there another perl function I can use to query only local users/groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no - the purpose of those function calls is to make the authentication mechanisms transparent. There's a variety of things you *could* be using, and no one wants to hand roll their own local files/ldap/yp/nis+/arbitrary PAM authentication mechanism.

If you're *specifically* interested in the contents of the local `passwd` and `group` files, I'd suggest the answer is - read those directly.

Comment: That is what I was trying to avoid as I keep reading everywhere it is poor practice to read the file instead of using provided mechanisms. Thanks though, my suspicions have been confirmed.

Comment: It is bad practice generally - you should use the os mechanisms when you can, because you don't (shouldn't) care about auth source. But a more important question is - _why_ is your stuff failing without a local group.  It should be using the exact same mechanisms.

Comment: The script checks for the existence of local users and groups and creates them if they are not found, if they are found set them to the group/user ID numbers provided by the input xml file. Problem is when using LDAP as an authentication source the os mechanisms will return LDAP results when there is an identical ldap group name. Trust me I wouldn't be doing it this way if I didn't have to, but its what happens when you inherit a code base and there is no budget for fixing the underlying issue... just add it to the "we need budget for..." list and keep on trucking.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. Real world makes a mess of "good practice" - you just need to know why you're going against it when you are :)